# How to combine user input into a score system (JFrame)

Tags: java

I am trying to make a proper marking system for my multiple choice quiz, but when I answer the quiz, only the default in my switch statement will appear, How can I put in the input?

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    int mark = 0;

    switch (mark) {
        case 5:

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "D");
            break;
        case 6:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "C");
            break;
        case 7: 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B");
            break;
        case 8:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A-");
            break;
        case 9:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A");
            break;
        case 10:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A+"); 
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "F");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You may wish to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead of directly looking for solution.

Comment: Please check the value of mark.

Comment: Do I  not initialize it?

Comment: You set the value of 'mark' to 0. But there is no 'case 0' so it goes to 'default'

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of mark. It is 0 hence default is showing.

Please check.

Please put break; statement in all case like.

```
  case 6: 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "C");
        break;
```

Comment: where? before each case

Comment: Please check the value of mark. It is 0 hence default is showing.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `break;` after each statement, otherwise the rest will be evaluated and the last will count.

Here's an example taken from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm):

```
switch(expression) {
   case value :
      // Statements
      break;

   case value :
      // Statements
      break;

   // You can have any number of case statements.
   default : // Optional
      // Statements
}
```